# Differentiating with MATLAB using jacobian and symbolic function

Tags: matlab

I'm running into an intriguing problem in MATLAB where I can't figure out a clean way to run the jacobian on a symbolic equation containing symbolic functions.

Let's say I have this equation for kinetic energy

[image: kinetic energy]

The variables `x` and `phi` are symbolic **functions** which when differentiated give `diff(x(t),t)` and `diff(phi(t),t)`

If I want to take the partial derivative of the coordinates (x_dot and phi_dot) like so

[image: partial]

I could do that if the variables were given as symbolic variables, **however**, in my case they are given as symbolic functions such as

```
diff(x(t),t)
diff(phi(t),t)
```

I could use the `subs()` function to substitute in symbolic variables but that can get messy quickly. Especially in this next step:

[image: time]

This would mean I have to re-substitute all those variables as functions so I can take the time derivative.

Any ideas on how I can easily derive these equations with the symbolic toolbox without lines and lines of code?

Comment: Show us example code where you set the symbolic variables up and how you could tackle this. Then it will be much easier for others to show you better methods...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the only thing you can do is using `subs` for this, but you can wrap it in a function like this:

```
function df = my_jacobian(f, x)
    x_ = sym('a', size(x));
    f_ = subs(f, x, x_);
    df_ = jacobian(f_, x_);
    df = subs(df_, x_, x);
end
```

Using this function you can calculate your jacobian similar to the example below:

```
syms x(t) y(t)

f = 2*diff(x(t), t) + 5*diff(y(t), t) + diff(x(t), t) * diff(y(t), t);
df = my_jacobian(f, [diff(x(t), t) diff(y(t), t)])
```